# avoid "Getting started with SAS" window when opening second SAS session

Tags: sas

How can the popup window ("getting started with sas") be prevented from displaying when opening a second SAS session (ie when a 'work' profile is used that does not contain your normal settings) ???

running

```
proc options internal; run;
```

reveals the TUTORIALDLG option, but I do not know the syntax to set this option at 'invocation' - (presumbably in the .CFG file..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the line

```
-NOTUTORIALDLG
```

to your config file *or* if you use the command line to start sas you can add the line to the startup command.  If you need to find the location of the config file your session is using, submit this command:

```
proc options option=config;run;
```